# Creating path using CGMutablePath creates line to wrong CGPoint

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

I was planning to display information of AR object in screen with arrow in 2D. So I used `projectPoint` to get corresponding position of object in screen. I have this function to return convert 3D position of node to 2D and `CGPoint` to display info text in.

```
func getPoint(sceneView: ARSCNView) -> (CGPoint, CGPoint){
    let projectedPoint = sceneView.projectPoint(node.worldPosition)
    return (point, CGPoint(x: CGFloat(projectedPoint.x), y: CGFloat(projectedPoint.y)) )
}
```

and this to draw line using `SpriteKit`:

```
let (f,s) = parts[3].getPoint(sceneView: sceneView) 
line.removeFromParent()
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.move(to: f)
path.addLine(to: s)
line = SKShapeNode(path: path)
spriteScene.addChild(line)
```

[This is what i get](https://media.giphy.com/media/4JSAlAy8UgWaA8pbXj/giphy.gif)

What I expect is another end of line to be fixed in node (blue mesh).
 Is there something I am missing? Or does `projectPoint` works some other way?

edit: It seems `projectPoint` is returning correct value but while creating path `path.addLine(to: s)` this point is shifting to different position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path.addLine(to: s)` s here had reversed y so this did the trick

```
let frame = self.sceneView.frame
let sInversed = CGPoint(x: from.x, y: frame.height - s.y)

path.addLine(to: sInversed)
```

Here origin of `SKScene` was in bottom left of screen instead of top left.

Comment: I am trying to do same thing from world coordinates, but showing the connected lines on uiview using bezierpath. I am getting very irregular shapes. Is it the wrong points ? (points taken for measuring room edges with sides aroung 3-5 meters)

Comment: I am trying to do same thing from world coordinates, but showing the connected lines on uiview using bezierpath. I am getting very irregular shapes. Is it the wrong points ? (points taken for measuring room edges with sides aroung 3-5 meters)

Comment: Not sure if uiview works same as SKSceneview. If you provide a more detail, maybe I can help you

Comment: Hi @AlokSubedi! I am trying to use project point for 3D face-tracking mesh to 2D image points in ARkit. Could you give me a hand?