# How to convert 2D points from 3D Points in ArKit iOS

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

How do I get the 2d points to plot on to uiview from 3d SCNNode.

Suppose I have following SCNNodes

```
pos(1.002163 -0.524722 -0.770023)
pos(1.174463 -0.765098 -0.607172)
pos(0.668790 -0.744061 -0.696863)
pos(0.781208 -0.744061 -1.228943)
```

And I need 2d points from above. I am new to Arkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [projectPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint)

```
let projectedPoint = sceneView.projectPoint(pos)
```

Comment: hi..alok i have tried your suggestion but sometimes it gives negative points so how to deal with it?

Comment: can you explain more? points may come outside of frame if node is not seen on screen.

Comment: I have converted the nodes from projectPoint() to 2d points and those are like below
pos(332.943787 1097.237915 0.998662)
pos(478.228455 1085.898193 0.998638)
pos(486.574646 1085.392700 0.998639)
pos(332.155975 1095.047607 0.998632)
i got "x" and "y" and ignore the "z" . But some times the x and y are negative and that was problem for me .?

Comment: I want to draw a frame on uiview like square from the four scnnode points. so help me regarding the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443228/creating-path-using-cgmutablepath-creates-line-to-wrong-cgpoint

Comment: And you need to overlay spriteScene with frame size equal to ARSceneView in the link above

Comment: Are those points get from projectPoint method are real uiview compatible points?

Comment: Yes as far as I know. The project in link I mentioned needed to track 3d point on real time and it gave great result.

Comment: hi @YogeshDalavi you got 2d coordinates (332.943787 1097.237915 0.998662). But an iPhone x max has only height less than 1000. So how did you manage 1097. Do we need to do any convertion ?

Comment: Yes you need to convert it to your scale so that it fit to your screen.

Comment: @AlokSubedi Can you please help on using project point with face-tracking SCNodes?

Comment: @swiftlearneer I am sorry, I cant. I have iPhone 8 so no truedepth camera.