# ARKit get 2d rect of 3d object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

so, I am new to ARKit and trying to figure it out. I have ARWorldTrackingConfiguration, with reference images (as shown below)

[image]

ARKit gives me the image as ARImageAnchor and its position in 3d space. But I want to know it's position(CGRect) in my ARSCNView, after I am done with this. I would like to convert my CGRect to 3d space again. I have applied these but couldn't get any valid results. The last one gives the correct x but y, width and height are not accurate.

- [How do it convert 2D Points From 3d Points in ArKit iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741286/how-do-it-convert-2d-points-from-3d-points-in-arkit-ios)
- [ARKit - Projection of ARAnchor to 2D space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49861366/arkit-projection-of-aranchor-to-2d-space)

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you checking wether width and height are correct? One potential issue is that your image can be rotated in your view

Comment: Hey @jlsiewert, this napkin is an example, my original object has a rectangular shape. Also, I have another validation process to check if it's rotated correctly. You see those ripple shapes on a napkin, let's say I want to know where the 15. row and 4. column ripple is and put some 3d object over it.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49443228/5567142)

Comment: What kind of content do you want to present over the napkin? 2D? 3D? Just an image?

Comment: Hey @AlokSubedi, i saw your answer but and tried it but it still return bigger rect than my screen.

Comment: Hey @beyowulf, let's say I give napkin image to ML Model and it returned me the position of every ripple and I would like to put 3d object over a couple of ripples. For this, I need to know where the napkin is in the buffer(get its 2d rect) and after I find my ripples I need to convert those 2d rects to 3d space position to put them over the napkin.

Comment: You're asking how to create an ML Model that will do image segmentation on the ripples in the napkin?

Comment: Nope, I am already able to get location and count of ripples over the napkin. But, I need to know the exact location of the napkin in the image before giving it to ML Model.

Comment: Are you using a `CoreML` model?

Comment: Yeap, there is no problem with ML, the only problem I have is that I couldn't convert the 3d position to 2d rect, then convert it back to 3d position.

Comment: You might look here https://github.com/Rightpoint/ARKit-CoreML/blob/master/Library/ARKit+Utilities.swift

Comment: I guess this is the example project i have been looking for, i will examine it and will tell you which part is the answer so you can write it as the answer and i can mark it as excepted. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @ysnzlcn! Did you get an answer for this? I need some help as I am working to get 3D to 2D point in ARkit as well!

Comment: @swiftlearneer no man if i had the answer, i would post it here.